# How do i fix this code? C# Ptr to a struct

Tags: c#, struct

As you may know, the wall rect will not update since its a copy and not a reference. Is there a way for me to make a reference or pointer to r and not change this code? I suppose i could do a find/replace in the function but that something i try not to do.

```
//code to get wall
var r = wall.r;
//more code
r.Height += yDif;
```

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand the question. What is 'wall' for a start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This of course requires a setter.

```
//code to get wall
var r = wall.r;
//more code
r.Height += yDif;
wall.r = r;
```

Comment: d'uh i could just set it again. Theres no if(blah) return; and its always updated. ok marked as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't going to work, you already know why.  Avoid the copy or simply store the copy back:

```
//more code
r.Height += yDif;
wall.r = r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you update directly the wall rect ?

```
//code to get wall
var r = wall.r;
//more code
wall.r.Height += yDif;
```